# Datalist not into text box when I'm trying to add my array's values to it as options

Tags: javascript, html

Newbie here. I have made a program in which you can type an expression in a text box and click in a button to submit it as an item to an array.I am attempting to make a datalist that has as options the values that are in that array, and
I have tried the solutions provided online, but couldn't make it work. Can you help me?

```
<!doctype html>

<html>

<head>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<button id="clearcustom" type="button">Show Modal</button>  

<textarea id="writefrase" rows="2" cols="25" placeholder="Write the expression you want to add to the array"></textarea>

<button id="submeter" type="button">Submit</button>

<div class="clearpopup">
    <div class="clearpopupheader">
        <span class="closeclearpopup">&times;</span>
        <p>Choose the option</p>
    </div>
    <div class="clearpopupcontent">
        <form>
            <input id="chooseclear" list="chooseclearlist" name="items" />
            <datalist id="chooseclearlist"></datalist>
        </form>
        <button id="clearpopupbutton">Choose</button>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

var TEF = [];

$("#submeter").click(function() {
    var newitem = $("#writefrase").val();
    if (newitem) {
        TEF.push(newitem);
         $("#writefrase").val("");
    }
});

let modalBtn = document.getElementById("clearcustom")
let modal = document.querySelector(".clearpopup")
let closeBtn = document.querySelector(".closeclearpopup")

modalBtn.onclick = function () {
    modal.style.display = "block"
}

closeBtn.onclick = function () {
     modal.style.display = "none"
}

</script>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why not use the HTML5 datalist element, instead of JavaScript?

Comment: I created the datalist in HTML 5, what could I do differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create the HTML that goes into your `<datalist>` with the values from the `TEF` variable.

Something like this does the trick:

```
<!doctype html>

<html>

<head>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<button id="clearcustom" type="button">Show Modal</button>  

<textarea id="writefrase" rows="2" cols="25" placeholder="Write the expression you want to add to the array"></textarea>

<button id="submeter" type="button">Submit</button>

<div class="clearpopup">
    <div class="clearpopupheader">
        <span class="closeclearpopup">&times;</span>
        <p>Choose the option</p>
    </div>
    <div class="clearpopupcontent">
        <form>
            <input id="chooseclear" list="chooseclearlist" name="items" />
            <datalist id="chooseclearlist"></datalist>
        </form>
        <button id="clearpopupbutton">Choose</button>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

var TEF = [];

function redrawDataList(){
  let options = [];
    TEF.forEach( el => {
        options.push(` <option value="${el}">`)
    })
    $("#chooseclearlist").html(options.join("\n"))
}

$("#submeter").click(function() {
    var newitem = $("#writefrase").val();
    if (newitem) {
        TEF.push(newitem);
         $("#writefrase").val("");
    }
    redrawDataList();
});

let modalBtn = document.getElementById("clearcustom")
let modal = document.querySelector(".clearpopup")
let closeBtn = document.querySelector(".closeclearpopup")

modalBtn.onclick = function () {
    modal.style.display = "block"
}

closeBtn.onclick = function () {
     modal.style.display = "none"
}

</script>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Weird, after trying this I am not being able to open the modal at all. Do you know what may be happening? Could it have to do with the CSS settings? Or may this be messing with other code I have?

Comment: I think the popup is not working with the HTML/js code you posted originally either.

Comment: it works in my project, only when I change my code to include yours it doesn't, I really don't understand why.

Comment: Ok, I found the modal. When the page starts it's already shown, right? 
Also, I tried closing it and redisplaying it and it seems to work. 
I am using the Chrome browser.

Try putting the whole code I posted in a separate page and see if that works.

Comment: I am very sorry, I forgot to mention the modal is hidden by default. I tried your code in a separate project and it worked. Also in Chrome.

Comment: if it worked in a separate page it means you copied it wrongly/incompletely in your page and you can upvote & accept this answer

Comment: I shall try again, I will upvote and accept it, I deeply appreciate your commitment to my question.

Comment: I tried to copy it again, replacing every part for the one in my application, and it sadly still didn't work. I tried to start with that and progressively add more elements from my original app to find the problem, and even though I set my local storage code, the datalist only works (it's a textbox before adding a new item) when I add a new item to TEF after refreshing the page. Real sad I am not being able to find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript `Array.prototype.includes()` method

```
 var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
  if (fruits.includes("Mango")) {
    console.log('Mango');
  }
```

Comment: sorry I don't understand how to use this in my situation. can you explain it to me?